# Using $translate in service does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translate, angular-translate

I want to use angular translate in service. I tried to load it using translatePartialLoader and then refresh but no success I am getting empty object in view. Below is my code.

***Service*

```
 angular
        .module('common')
        .factory('ConversationService', conversationService);

      function conversationService($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
        $translate.refresh();

        var asdsa;

        asdsa = $translate('home.test');
        console.log(asdsa);


       /* Tried with then also no success.. 
       $translate("home").then (function (home) {
          asdsa = home;
          console.log(asdsa);
        });*/
 }
```

})();

**app.js**  where I define $translate

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });

  function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $logProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: '/src/app/modules/{part}/resources/{lang}.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

**en.json file**

```
{
  "home" :{
    "test": "Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest",
  }
}
```

In controller I am using in resolve method translatePartialLodaer and is working but this way where I need for service it is not working. Below is how I am using in routes which is working.

```
     resolve: {
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
                  return $translate.refresh();
                }]
              }
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. because I faced this issue. Then checked with this .then function,\

Answer (score 0):

$translate is async fn, you should use it like

```
$translate('token.token2').then(function(translation){
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. If I understand correct if I try this: $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
        $translate.refresh();

        var homeTranslation;

        $translate('home').then(function(translation){
          homeTranslation = translation;
          console.log(homeTranslation);
        });
homeTranslation should have all values defined in en.json but it is undefined. It never goes inside .then

Comment: Is your app receive translations file ? Check network tav of debugger

Comment: Yup..before this service is called I can see en.json file in network tab. Also as I wrote before the I am loading in resolve method in routes and using in view it is working great.